# Google site - provide user to embed form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have a google site. In one of the pages i want to embed my own form already developed and hosted which works fine. The problem is that i want to provide the logged user on the google site to the form. I tried google apps script and it seems that i can get the logged user with

```
Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
```

But then i have no idea how to continue. Could i load the form like iframe from google apps scripts somehow ? Or if i can somehow add the user as query string ? Already checked out a lot of information, but most of it looks outdate and confusing. Actually it's not necessary to load my hosted form ..seems like it's possible to build form in google apps script and then i can just hit my other endpoint API.

Answer (score 0):

The options at your disposal depend on which Sites version you are using.

For example, in [new Sites](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#embedding_a_web_app_in_new_sites), you can deploy your Apps Script as a web app and embed it to the Site in a frame:

> The web app appears in a frame in the page's preview. When you publish the page, your site viewers may need to authorize the web app before it executes normally. Unauthorized web apps present authorization prompts to the user.

In [classic Sites](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#embedding_a_web_app_in_classic_sites), you can also bind your script to the site in a similar fashion to how you can bind scripts to Google editors.

#### Reference:

- [Deploy a script as a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app)
- [Embedding your web app in Google Sites](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#embedding_your_web_app_in_google_sites)